# Programmatically insert entry to dynamic web.config of ASP.NET Core Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, web-config

Using Visual Studio 2017, I created an ASP.NET Core Web App (Core 2.1).  In Visual Studio, it has no web.config file, but works fine using F6 to run.
I am hosting it at host company DiscountASP.NET.  To publish it out to the host, I use Visual Studio’s Web Deploy feature, which works great.

In my root folder at DiscountASP.NET, a web.config file suddenly appears, as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CoreWbApSH01.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: a532f7f5-c3da-40e3-9158-00bcc9555660-->
```

So far, so good. Everything works great.

MY NEED: Now, when a visitor hits the site, I want to force http to https.  The hosting company has a way to do that, explained in their article here:
[DASP KnowledgeBase](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1464/web-browser-security-warnings-after-installing-ssl-certificate.aspx?KBSearchID=689322)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This above xml indeed worked well.  But to get it to work, I had first Web Deploy to my folder at DiscountASP.NET, then manually FTP into that folder, and manually edit the more or less ephemeral web.config file there, inserting the `<rewrite>` segment.

This works great, except that every time I edit the website and re-deploy, I have to then manually FTP in and edit the web.config file again.

**My question is this:**  In Visual Studio 2017, is there a way I can programmatically get that  segment to be inserted automatically into the ephemeral web.config that appears when I deploy to DiscountASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to enforce HTTPS, rather than trying to modify the web.config file, you can add code to your application startup code (ConfigureServices) to enforce HTTPS.

In production ASP.NET Core web apps, call HTTPS Redirection Middleware (UseHttpsRedirection) to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS.

There are some caveats when deploying a Web API project.

For a complete answer to your question, [read this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: I already read that article Phantom2018.  And VS 2017 already calls UseHttpsRedirection() in Startup.cs, and it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks.